# How to scrape element's value without knowing it in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am new to puppeteer and javascript, I want to get value of src, which is a link to image. The problem is, that it's different every time. The whole div looks like on
[div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoztp.png).

"id" and "src" is always different, I have to scrape src value. I didn't try anything because I don't even know how to do it.
Code as a text:

```
<img id="wlspispHIPBimg0e90cc22c0a20496ba89e3abfd4fec7790" aria-label="Visual Challenge" alt="Visual Challenge" src="https://WUS.client.hip.live.com:443/GetHIPData?hid=WUS.7e26f468ff8143888d4817c318505e42&amp;fid=9cd580a0862f483885b57dffd2d0d27f&amp;id=15041&amp;type=visual&amp;cs=HIPAMFE" class="text-body" style="display: inline; width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 200px;">
```

Comment: Welcome! Please use code in text format, instead of a screenshot. It becomes easier to copy and is useful for SEO.

Comment: Can you target it by another attribute or a parent element that always has the same id/class/etc?

Comment: @Phix how can I do it? Can you please send me just an example of how should it look like in code?

Comment: I can't since I don't have the source, but like I said if there's a parent element that has a class, ID, or other unique identifier you should be able to access the image element from there. As your question sits now it's impossible to tell for sure.